# Toggle class on span when link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Updated code example of what I'm trying to acheive. the featuredToggle even triggers the checkbox click event and then should toggle the css class on the #featured-icon, but it does not add the class.

```
<a class='favorite-btn' onclick="featuredToggle()">
                <span id='featured-icon' class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                <input id="featured-toggle" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: featured"/>
            </a>

function featuredToggle() { 
   $("#featured-toggle").trigger('click');
   $("#featured-icon").toggleClass('featured');
}
```

Comment: The JsFiddle you posted has a syntax error in the JavaScript code, single and double quote.

Comment: Your jsFiddle does not match your question

Comment: Makes no sense, you have an anchor without an href, which is OK in HTML5, but why? And, you  can't trigger a click with a callback function, that's not the way it works at all?

Comment: js fiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/gLBmX/3/

Comment: the href was there when I mocked up the html...forgot to remove it.

Comment: Basically I have a checkbox that is bound with knockout and hidden, so that you use a star to check or uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: You're still not really getting it, read the documentation for `trigger()`, it has no callback, just extra parameters, so you call it by doing `$("#featured-toggle").trigger('click')`, and that's it, you can't add a function with stuff to do, all it does is trigger the event ?

Comment: OK. I get that...that's not the issue though. I have updated the code to just call toggle and then added a line to toggle the css class for an element with an id and still the css class is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to do this :

```
$(".favorite-btn").click(function () {
    $("#featured-toggle").prop('checked', function(_,ckd) {return !ckd});
    $("#featured-icon").toggleClass('active');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gLBmX/6/)

Comment: And what context is that ?

Answer (score 0):

First you are using JQuery and not plain javascript. So within your JSFiddle you would have to select a JQuery library from the drop down. You would also have to close off some invalid quotes, but even then it wont work.

Here's a fiddle I made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/gLBmX/21/

```
$(function() {  
    $("#featured-toggle").click(function() {  
        $("#featured-icon").toggleClass("active");  
    });  
});
```

Whenever #featured-toggle is clicked toggle the "active" class on #featured-icon.

Hopefully that helps you a bit!